# Fuzzy search on large table

Tags: postgresql, autocomplete, lucene, bigdata, fuzzy-search

I have a very large PostgreSQL table with 12M names and I would like to show an autocomplete. Previously I used a `ILIKE "someth%"` clause but I'm not really satisfied with it. For example it doesn't sort by similarity and any spelling error would cause wrong or no results. The field is a string, usually one or two words (in any language). I need a fast response because suggestions are shown live to the user while he is typing (i.e. autocomplete). I cannot restrict the fuzzy match to a subset because all names are equally important. I can also say that most names are different.

I have tried pg_trgm but even with a gin index is very slow. The search of a name similar to 'html' takes a few milliseconds, but - don't ask me why - other searches like 'htm' take a lot of seconds - e.g. 25 seconds. Also other people has reported performance issues with pg_trgm on large tables.

Is there anything I can do to efficiently show an autocomplete on that field?
Would a full text search engine (e.g. Lucene, Solr) be an appropriate solution? Or I would encounter the same inefficiency?

Comment: Did you take a look at full text search? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/textsearch.html

Comment: @FrankHeikens it is not what I am looking for, it doesn't support fuzzy matching: "Trigram matching is a very useful tool when used in conjunction with a full text index. In particular it can help to recognize misspelled input words that will not be matched directly by the full text search mechanism." I know that full text allows the use of a sort of thesaurus, but that's not the same thing.

Comment: Try ElasticSearch ortherwise look into simhash (or fuzzbuzz).